# Order by sum column relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this controller which grabs posts from a post table.
Every post in the *posts* table have the relation "hasMany" with another table *likes*.

**Controller:**

```
public function getDashboard(){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); 

        return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

I'd like to replace 'created at' with something like:

```
$post->likes->sum(like)
```

Don't know how to write the right syntax though.

**EDIT:**

Here are the tables.

```
Posts  
--id   
--body  
Likes 
--id  
--post_id  
--like
```

The column *like* can have the value 1 or -1.
I'd like to order on the summation of that column for each post.
So a post with one dislike(-1) and one like(1) will have the aggregated value of 0, hence will be placed after a post with one like(1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) for this as:

```
Post::withCount('likes')->orderBy('likes_count')->get()
```

> `withCount()` will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting
>   models

**Update**

```
Post::withCount(['likes' => function($q) {
    $q->where('like', 1)
}])
->orderBy('likes_count')
->get()
```

**Update2**

You can use [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortbydesc) to sort your collection as:

```
$posts = Post::get();

$posts = $posts->sortByDesc(function ($post) {
            return $post->likes->sum('like');
        });
```

Comment: That helped. The only thing is I'll implement a dislike function. Now it's ordering on the post with most rows within the _likes_ table.


A column called like within the _likes_ table will be able to take the value 1 or -1.
Therefor I was thinking that some kind of column summation would have been best suited.

Comment: Sorry, I was too unclear about what i wanted. 
I updated the original post

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sum column value from relationship and then sort records.

```
$users = User::addSelect(['likes' => Post::selectRaw('sum(likes) as total_likes')
     ->whereColumn('user_id', 'useres.id')
     ->groupBy('user_id')
 ])
 ->orderBy('likes', 'DESC')
 ->get()
 ->toArray();
```

Or
use below

```
$users = User::select("*", 
               \DB::raw('(SELECT SUM(likes) FROM likes_table WHERE likes_table.user_id = users.id) as tolal_likes'))
        ->orderBy('likes', 'DESC')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```